# Sharing classes between existing iPhone project and Watch Kit extension

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, linker, watchkit

I would like to share a class "MyClass" that I added as target to an iPhone project to which I then added a Watch Kit extension target.

Whenever I import the "MyClass" in the Watch Kit extension source code I get:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyClass",
>   referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in WKMyInterfaceController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with
>   exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any idea on how to solve this? It seems a linker problem so I guess I have to add the source code of the class MyClass to the linked libraries/headers of the WatchKit Extension app but I am not sure if there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to select both target for you MyClass.

If you are using objective c then go to your MyClass's .m file and select the target as your watch kit also.

[image: Check out the screenshot here]

Hope this will help you.